# Getting "Run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed"

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have two (2) sheets. The first one has a button. The second sheet is my summary page, and I plan to have a button here that is linked to the button on my first sheet. However, I get the

> Run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed.

I assigned Command1_Click() to be my button at Sheet2

Module1:

```
Sub Command1_Click()
Call Model01
End Sub
```

Module2:

```
Sub Model01()
Sheet1.Range("C8:GF8").Value = Sheet1.Range("C240:GF240").Value
Sheet1.Range("B7").Value = Sheet1.Range("B240").Value
r = DataUpdate()
End Sub
```

Module3:

```
Function DataUpdate()
If (validateVer() = False) Then
    Exit Function
End If

Dim AsCn, AsRs, SQL
Dim x, y, WDATE, NGQTY, FAQTY, RWQTY, RNQTY, TotalCell, TotalCellx
Dim FA_TBL As Variant   ' (y, x)
Dim RW_TBL As Variant   ' (y, x)
Dim RN_TBL As Variant   ' (y, x)
Dim NG_TBL As Variant   ' (y, x)


'Sheet => Table
Sheet1.Range("C2:GS2").Select
Selection.ClearContents
FA_TBL = Sheet1.Range("A2:GS2")
Sheet1.Range("C4:GS4").Select
Selection.ClearContents
RW_TBL = Sheet1.Range("A4:GS4")
Sheet1.Range("C5:GS5").Select
Selection.ClearContents
RN_TBL = Sheet1.Range("A5:GS5")
Sheet1.Range("A9:GS208").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheet1.Range("C9").Select
NG_TBL = Sheet1.Range("A8:GS208")

'Connect DataBase ODBC
Set AsCn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
AsCn.Open "Provider=IBMDA400;Data Source=FCP2040;", "FCPMIS", "AUTOSENT"
'AsCn.Open "dsn=FCP2040;uid=FCPMIS;pwd=AUTOSENT"

'Get Total cell
TotalCell = 3
While NG_TBL(1, TotalCell) <> "Total"
    TotalCell = TotalCell + 1
Wend
```

..

```
'Get NG Qty
y = 2
NGQTY = 0
While Not (AsRs.EOF)

    NG_TBL(y, 1) = AsRs(1)
    NG_TBL(y, 2) = AsRs(2)
    NGQTY = 0
    x = 3
    While x < TotalCell
        WDATE = Right(Year(NG_TBL(1, x)), 2) & Right("00" & Month(NG_TBL(1, x)), 2) & Right("00" & Day(NG_TBL(1, x)), 2)
        If Not (AsRs.EOF) Then
            If ((NG_TBL(y, 1) = AsRs(1)) And _
                ((WDATE = AsRs(0)) Or ((x + 1) = TotalCell))) Then
                NG_TBL(y, x) = AsRs(3)
                NGQTY = NGQTY + AsRs(3)
                AsRs.MoveNext
            Else
                If FA_TBL(1, x) <> "" Then
                    NG_TBL(y, x) = 0
                End If
            End If
        Else
            If FA_TBL(1, x) <> "" Then
                NG_TBL(y, x) = 0
            End If
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Wend
    NG_TBL(y, TotalCell) = NGQTY
    y = y + 1
Wend

'Sheet => Table
Sheet1.Range("A2:GS2") = FA_TBL
Sheet1.Range("A4:GS4") = RW_TBL
Sheet1.Range("A5:GS5") = RN_TBL
Sheet1.Range("A8:GS208") = NG_TBL


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'   Sort
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
If (TotalCell \ 26) = 0 Then
    TotalCellx = Chr(TotalCell + 64)
Else
    TotalCellx = Chr(TotalCell \ 26 + 64) & Chr(TotalCell Mod 26 + 64)
End If

Sheet1.Range("A8:" & TotalCellx & "100").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range(TotalCellx & "9"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess _
    , OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    SortMethod:=xlPinYin
Sheet1.Range("C9").Select



'Close Recordset
AsRs.Close
Set AsRs = Nothing

'Close DataBase ODBC
AsCn.Close
Set AsCn = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only select a range on an active sheet. Hence you can't directly select a range in `Sheet1` from a button in `Sheet2`. The solution is not to activate the sheet before selecting. The solution is to not use `Select` at all. That method is almost never needed. For example

```
Sheet1.Range("C2:GS2").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

is more cleanly expressed as

```
Sheet1.Range("C2:GS2").ClearContents
```

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4996248) for other suggestions for eliminating needless selects in your code.